# Sum of all lattice triangles

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, geometry

I came across a question which I state as follows :- 
A triangle is called a *lattice triangle* if all its sides are positive integers. For such a lattice triangle, with side a opposite to vertex A, b opposite to vertex B, c opposite to vertex C 
Find 
$$\sum_{a,b,c}\frac{(2^a)}{(3^b)(5^c)}$$

Please help me out. Although, there are infinitely many triangles, The sum is said to be not infinite. I have tried to solve this using Normal Algebraic methods and gave it a shot with Complex Numbers and polar co-ordinates too, but could not make anything out. Please solve this question somehow. I just seemed to understand that 
$$\sum_{a,b,c}\frac{(2^a)}{(3^b)(5^c)}$$
$$= \sum_{a}\sum_{b}\sum_{c}(\frac{(2^a)}{(3^b)(5^c)}+\frac{(2^a)}{(3^c)(5^b)}+\frac{(2^b)}{(3^a)(5^c)}+\frac{(2^b)}{(3^c)(5^a)}+\frac{(2^c)}{(3^a)(5^b)}+\frac{(2^c)}{(3^b)(5^a)})$$
But could not move forward after this. Please help.

Thanks for your time

Comment: In a first step, assume that you have the following order: $a \ge b \ge c$ ; therefore, for a fixed value of $a$, there are (indeed) a finite number of possible values for $b$ and $c$ that you can count ; for example, if $a=5$, you can take $(b=5, c=5), (b=5, c=4), ... (b=3, c=3)$ (take care to exclude flat triangles).

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for your suggestion... I tried that by parameterizing all sides, considering a = k, where 'k' can go from 1 to infinity, b = k - d, where 'd' can go from 0 to k-1, and c = 2k-d-a, where a can go from 1 to 2k-d-1... , but when I put them accordingly, I need to sum over (2/15) raised to k, multiplied to (15) raised to d, multiplied to (5) raised to a. While summing accordingly, I need to sum over 2 raised to k at the last step, where k lies between 1 to infinity. Clearly, this shall produce infinity. Is there any workaround? Any different parameterization or something else?

Comment: I got an answer to this, but shall not post now. I invite solutions to this problem without any urgency. Thank you.